# How do I add an Office 365 Group to SharePoint Site programatically

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

I am having some trouble adding an Office 365 group to a SharePoint App through CSOM.

The following code used to work

```
 var secPrincipalName = "Office 365 Group Name";
 sharepointTempUser = web.EnsureUser(secPrincipalName);
 ctx.Load(sharepointTempUser);
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

What I have discovered is that adding the group by name no longer works.

How can I Ensure a O365 Group through CSOM?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the **web.EnsureUser** method to get the Security Group from the Azure AD.

If you want to add the **Offices 365 Group** to SharePoint, we need use **[Tenant.CreateGroupForSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.creategroupforsite.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** method to achieve it.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/");
var pwd = "mypassword";
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@mydomain.com", passWord);
Tenant tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
GroupCreationParams optionalParams = new GroupCreationParams(tenant.Context);
optionalParams.Description = "description";
optionalParams.CreationOptions = new string[] { "SharePointKeepOldHomepage" };
tenant.CreateGroupForSite("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/team-site", "display-name-for-group", "alias-for-group", true, optionalParams);
```

Comment: Hi LZ, thanks for your response, however I am not looking to create a new group. I want to user an existing Azure AD group. The web.EnsureUser("groupName") method throws an exception. But if I use web.EnsureUser("group saml id") I think it works in my case. Can you confirm if using a SAML id would work consistently across all SharePoint Online tenants?

Comment: @TariqAyad I am facing the same situation. Did you managed to solve it using the groupname? And how can i obtain the SAML id?